# How to get the objects in an array based on particular string

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I have an array which contains the objects like below
 "04_Num",

```
  "04_Num/04Num.m3u",
    "04_Num/04Num001.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num002.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num003.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num004.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num005.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num006.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num007.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num008.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num009.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num010.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num011.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num012.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num013.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num014.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num015.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num016.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num017.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num018.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num019.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num020.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num021.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num022.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num023.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num024.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num025.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num026.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num027.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num028.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num029.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num030.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num031.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num032.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num033.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num034.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num035.mp3",
    "04_Num/04Num036.mp3"
```

but here i want the objects only which contains .mp3 extension and then i have to place those objects into another array

how it is possible if any body know this please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate and get only the one that has .mp3

Like so

```
//yourArrayThatContainsAllStrings contains all the strings
NSMutableArray *arrayOfMp3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *str in yourArrayThatContainsAllStrings) {
    if ([str rangeOfString:@".mp3"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [arrayOfMp3 addObject:str];
    }
}

//arrayOfMp3 will contain only the .mp3 files
```

Comment: @user1416377 you are welcome, please consider to upvote and/or accept answer if this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *mpthrees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (NSString *file in songs) //Where songs is the array with the paths you have provided
{
    BOOL isMpthree = [[file pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"mp3"];
    if (isMpthree) [mpthrees addObject:file];
}
// Now mpthrees array holds only paths pointing to .mp3 files
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Let's call your array of strings as stringsArray
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *str in stringsArray) {
    if ([str hasSuffix:@".mp3"]) {
        [filteredArray addObject:str];
    } }

//filteredArray will contain only the strings ending with ".mp3"
```

P.S. Since you're just beginning Objective C, i would like to reiterate that Objective C NSString objects always start with an @ symbol. @"04_Num/04Num001.mp3"